# Is it possible to use Firebase to direct requests to a Cloud Run container which is in another project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting

So on the official firebase documentation it looks pretty straightforward to see that we can direct requests to our Cloud Run via proxy.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-cloud-run-container

So its says if you add your cloud run's serviceId it will be done:

```
"hosting": {
 // ...

 // Directs all requests from the page `/helloworld` to trigger and run a `helloworld` container
 "rewrites": [ {
   "source": "/helloworld",
   "run": {
     "serviceId": "helloworld",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
     "region": "us-central1"  // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
   }
 } ]
}
```

However this does not cover my problem where you have different projects so you cannot directly give the container image/ service name. They are on the same account but in different projects.

I tried giving the direct destination:

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "destination": "MY-CLOUD-RUN-APP-URL>/api/**"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
```

However this didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.  The configured Cloud Run instances must be in the same project as Firebase Hosting.

You could possibly set up a Cloud Run container to forward/proxy HTTP requests to another publicly accessible Cloud Run instance in another project (or any other HTTP service for that matter).

Comment: Thanks, I will move my backend and frontend to the same project then.